# postgresql group by

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by

This is my query in Postgresql:

```
SELECT 
    C.id, S.domen, B.name, C.source_id, ST.name 
FROM "calls" C 
    INNER JOIN "site" S ON S.id=C.site_id 
    INNER JOIN "sources" ON sources.id=C.source_id 
    INNER JOIN "brand" B ON B.id = S.id_brand
    INNER JOIN "source_types" ST ON ST.id = "sources".type_id 
WHERE 
    ("calltime" >= '2017-12-01') AND 
    ("calltime" <= '2017-12-03') AND 
    (S."id_brand"='6') 
ORDER BY "calltime" LIMIT 50
```

And I get this result:

[image]

Now I am trying to group by name(last column) this result to get result like this:

```
Контекстная реклама - 17
SEO-10
....
```

And for this I use this query:

```
SELECT 
    ST.name, count(ST.name) 
FROM "calls" C 
    INNER JOIN "site" S ON S.id=C.site_id 
    INNER JOIN "sources" ON sources.id=C.source_id 
    INNER JOIN "brand" B ON B.id = S.id_brand
    INNER JOIN "source_types" ST ON ST.id = "sources".type_id 
WHERE 
    ("calltime" >= '2017-12-01') AND 
    ("calltime" <= '2017-12-03') AND 
    (S."id_brand"='6') 
GROUP BY ST.name 
ORDER BY count(ST.name) DESC LIMIT 50
```

But I am getting wrong result:

[image]

Seems like it take values from `source_id` column. 
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try `count(*)` instead

Comment: @Phil, The result is the same

Answer (score 1):

Try this, If you call group by before limit the result then group by for the entire records. So first filter then do the group by.

```
    SELECT 
        name, count(name) 
    FROM(
    SELECT 
        ST.name 
    FROM "calls" C 
        INNER JOIN "site" S ON S.id=C.site_id 
        INNER JOIN "sources" ON sources.id=C.source_id 
        INNER JOIN "brand" B ON B.id = S.id_brand
        INNER JOIN "source_types" ST ON ST.id = "sources".type_id 
    WHERE 
        ("calltime" >= '2017-12-01') AND 
        ("calltime" <= '2017-12-03') AND 
        (S."id_brand"='6') 
    ORDER BY "calltime" LIMIT 50
    ) T 
    GROUP BY name
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the 49 is just a coincidence.  Try:

```
SELECT 
    ST.name, count(*) 
FROM "calls" C 
    INNER JOIN "site" S ON S.id=C.site_id 
    INNER JOIN "sources" ON sources.id=C.source_id 
    INNER JOIN "brand" B ON B.id = S.id_brand
    INNER JOIN "source_types" ST ON ST.id = "sources".type_id 
WHERE 
    ("calltime" >= '2017-12-01') AND 
    ("calltime" <= '2017-12-03') AND 
    (S."id_brand"='6') AND 
    C.source_id > 50
GROUP BY ST.name 
ORDER BY count(*) DESC LIMIT 50
```

All I did was change it to `count(*)` and add  `AND C.source_id > 50` to the Where clause.  Let's see if this changes the count.

Also you could just run this:

```
SELECT 
    count(*) 
FROM "calls" C 
    INNER JOIN "site" S ON S.id=C.site_id 
    INNER JOIN "sources" ON sources.id=C.source_id 
    INNER JOIN "brand" B ON B.id = S.id_brand
    INNER JOIN "source_types" ST ON ST.id = "sources".type_id 
WHERE 
    ("calltime" >= '2017-12-01') AND 
    ("calltime" <= '2017-12-03') AND 
    (S."id_brand"='6')
```

This gives you a total count of all the rows (I removed the GROUP BY).  If this number equals the total of your grouped row counts, then they really are the counts. We are looking for `127` which is `49 + 30 + 21 + 13 + 9 + 4 + 1`

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT 50` in the second query is executed *after* the `GROUP BY`.

If you want to aggregate only the first 50 lines, write the `LIMIT 50` into a subselect and perform the `GROUP BY` in the outer `SELECT`.